# How to save AWS Cloudwatch resources metric data point in some other database

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch, influxdb, aws-application-load-balancer

As I know that AWS CloudWatch store metric datapoint for 15 months with variable data point sampling like

1. 01 sec DP for 3 hours
2. 60 sec DP for 15 Days
3. 300 sec DP for 63 Days and so on

But there is no data available before 15 months also the available data is not helpful due to large data sample size

In my case, I am looking for some metric of ALB like

1. Max Active Connection per minute,
2. Max Request count per minute(RPM) &
3. New connection count

before 15 months, somehow I was able to identify max RPM via parsing ALB access logs.

I am looking for some solution which is easy to use and storing data in time serise DB (ex: influx DB)

Answer (score 0):

Use&configure Telegraf [Amazon CloudWatch Statistics Input Plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/cloudwatch) and save CloudWatch metrics into InfluxDB.